# Smarty Template Organization

Tags: php, smarty

I've set up Smarty and my basic structure is this:

www.domain.com/html -- This is where all the .php files live.
www.domain.com/smarty/templates -- This is where all the .tpl files live.

Now, everything works well for files in the web root directory (html), but I'm not sure what to do when I put .php files in a separate folder under the root e.g. www.domain.com/html/folder/. I want to do this to organize a bunch of related pages under that new folder. I still place all the .tpl files under the www.domain.com/smarty/templates folder. When I try to display a page under that new folder e.g. ww.domain.com/html/folder/, the resources for the page (CSS, images, etc.) are missing i.e. are not being fetched. What's the proper way to organize the files for this scenario?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your config for template_dir, compile_dir, cache_dir, and config_dir are using full absolute path (ex. /home/httpd/vhosts/[yourdomain.com].... or whatever it is with a trailing /).

Make sure you reference your CSS/Images using absolute path from the root. So if your css is in a folder [ROOT]/css, your HTML would call the CSS like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" type="text/css">`

It doesn't matter where the templates are and where your PHP files are. When they are loaded into PHP the template is just that, a template, and all your pathing takes place from the perspective of the PHP file.

Comment: When doing templates that share a header file or something, you awlays want to use absolute pathing from the root for resources so that no matter where the php file calling the template is, it is able to get your resources.